# Ajax auto refresh - PHP variables not passing correctly into auto refresh function

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

I'm using Eliza Witkowska's Ajax Auto Refresh code: http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/entry/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii

I've altered the code so I can pass variables from the url.  It all works great except for one line of code.  The line of code is part of a database query that checks for new records.  When I try to pass my variables into the query the auto refresh stops working (all other functionality continues to work).  If I use static values it works fine.

static values (this works)

```
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM chats WHERE id=1 AND AgentID=3 AND UserID=25');
```

with variables  (this doesn't work)

```
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM chats WHERE id=1 AND AgentID='.$AgentID.' AND UserID='.$UserID.'');
```

There are no problems passing variables into another function in the same script.  So I'm stuck and have been for a few days.  Any help with be appreciated.

db.php

```
class db{

/**
 * db
 *
 * @var $   public $db;
 */
public $db;

function __construct(){
    $this->db_connect('###SERVER###','###USERNAME###','###PASSWORD###','###DATABASE###');   //my database information
}

function db_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database){
    $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

    if($this->db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
    }
}

//////////////////////////////
//This is the function that is having an issue when I pass it variables
//////////////////////////////

function check_changes(){
    global $UserID;     //Declaring my variable
    global $AgentID;    //Declaring my variable
    $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM chats WHERE id=1 AND AgentID='.$AgentID.' AND UserID='.$UserID.'');

    if($result = $result->fetch_object()){
        return $result->counting;
    }
    return 0;
}


//////////////////////////////
//This function has no problem, even when I pass it variables
//////////////////////////////
function get_news(){
    global $UserID;
    global $AgentID;
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM chats WHERE id<>1 AND AgentID='.$AgentID.' AND UserID='.$UserID.' ORDER BY add_date ASC LIMIT 50')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            if ($r->ChatType==1) {      //ChatType is a field in the table that distinguishes Agent texts from User Texts
                $return .= ''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).'';
            } else {
                $return .= '<div align="right">'.htmlspecialchars($r->title).'</div>';
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}


}
```

Here are the other files:

index.php

```
<?php
$AgentID = $_REQUEST["AgentID"];  //Grabing AgentID from the URL
$UserID = $_REQUEST["UserID"];    //Grabing UserID from the URL
require('common.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Admin</title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /* AJAX request to checker */
    function check(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checker.php?AgentID=<? echo $AgentID; ?>&UserID=<? echo $UserID; ?>',  //This line has been updated by passing parameters
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                counter:$('#message-list').data('counter')
            }
        }).done(function( response ) {
            /* update counter */
            $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
            /* check if with response we got a new update */
            if(response.update==true){
                $('#message-list').html(response.news);
                var audio = new Audio('img/solemn.mp3');
                audio.play();
            }
        });
    }
    //Every 2 sec check if there is new update
    setInterval(check,2000);
</script>
<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php /* Our message container. data-counter should contain initial value of counter from database */ ?>
<br>
<div id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes();?>">
    <?php echo $db->get_news();?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

checker.php

```
<?php require('common.php');
//get current counter
$data['current'] = (int)$db->check_changes();
//set initial value of update to false
$data['update'] = false;
//check if it's ajax call with POST containing current (for user) counter;
//and check if that counter is diffrent from the one in database
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && (int)$_POST['counter']!=$data['current']){
$AgentID = $_REQUEST["AgentID"];  //passing my variable to db.php
$UserID = $_REQUEST["UserID"];    //passing my variable to db.php
$data['news'] = $db->get_news();
$data['update'] = true;
}
//just echo as JSON
echo json_encode($data);
/* End of file checker.php */
?>
```

common.php

```
<?php
require_once ('db.php'); //get our database class
$db = new db();
/* end of file common.php */
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was that the variables were not available at the time of including the database connection in `checker.php` ~ declare the variables and then include the db connection.

Also, I'd suggest that instead of using the `global` expression to define the variables within your db class methods that you pass them as parameters instead. I hope the following might be of use - it's not tested though. There are, or should be, concerns with this method of using variables within sql - it is vulnerable to the dreaded `sql injection` ~ better would be to use `prepared statements` within the db class and bind the `$agentID` and `$UserID` with the `bind_param()` method.

```
<?php
    /* common.php */

    $dbhost =   'xxx';
    $dbuser =   'xxx'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';

    require_once 'db.php';
    $db = new db( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
?>


<?php
    /* database class: db.php */
    class db{
        private $db;

        public function __construct( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname ){
            $this->db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
            if( $this->db->connect_errno > 0 ) exit('Unable to connect to database [' . $this->db->connect_error . ']');
        }

        public function check_changes( $AgentID=false, $UserID=false ){
            if( $AgentID && $UserID ){
                $result = $this->db->query('SELECT counting FROM chats WHERE id=1 AND AgentID='.$AgentID.' AND UserID='.$UserID.'');
                if($result = $result->fetch_object()){
                    return $result->counting;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public function get_news( $AgentID, $UserID ){
            $return = '';
            if( $AgentID && $UserID ){
                if( $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM chats WHERE id<>1 AND AgentID='.$AgentID.' AND UserID='.$UserID.' ORDER BY add_date ASC LIMIT 50' ) ){
                    while( $r = $result->fetch_object() ){
                        if ($r->ChatType==1) {
                            $return .= ''.htmlspecialchars($r->title).'';
                        } else {
                            $return .= '<div align="right">'.htmlspecialchars($r->title).'</div>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $return;
            }
        }
    }
?>


<?php 
    /* Checker.php */
    $AgentID = isset( $_REQUEST["AgentID"] ) ? $_REQUEST["AgentID"] : false;
    $UserID = isset( $_REQUEST["UserID"] ) ? $_REQUEST["UserID"] : false;   

    if( $AgentID && $UserID ){

        /* Do SOME filtering of user supplied data */
        $AgentID=filter_var( $AgentID, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, array( 'options' => array('default' => 0, 'min_range' => 0 ) ) );
        $UserID=filter_var( $UserID, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, array( 'options' => array('default' => 0, 'min_range' => 0 ) ) );

        require 'common.php';

        $data['current'] = (int)$db->check_changes( $AgentID, $UserID );
        $data['update'] = false;

        if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && (int)$_POST['counter']!=$data['current'] ){
            $data['news'] = $db->get_news( $AgentID, $UserID );
            $data['update'] = true;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
?>

<?php
    $AgentID = isset( $_REQUEST["AgentID"] ) ? $_REQUEST["AgentID"] : false;
    $UserID = isset( $_REQUEST["UserID"] ) ? $_REQUEST["UserID"] : false;

    $AgentID=filter_var( $AgentID, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, array( 'options' => array('default' => 0, 'min_range' => 0 ) ) );
    $UserID=filter_var( $UserID, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, array( 'options' => array('default' => 0, 'min_range' => 0 ) ) );

    require 'common.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Admin</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            <?php

            echo "
                var aid={$AgentID};
                var uid={$UserID};";

            ?>
            function check(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'checker.php?AgentID='+aid+'&UserID='+uid,
                    dataType:'json',
                    data:{ counter:$('#message-list').data('counter') }
                }).done( function( response ) {
                    /* update counter */
                    $('#message-list').data('counter',response.current);
                    /* check if with response we got a new update */
                    if(response.update==true){
                        $('#message-list').html(response.news);
                        var audio = new Audio('img/solemn.mp3');
                        audio.play();
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(check,2000);
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:0px;
                padding:0px;
                vertical-align:top;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div id="message-list" data-counter="<?php echo (int)$db->check_changes($AgentID, $UserID); ?>">
            <?php echo $db->get_news($AgentID, $UserID);?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoa, thanks a ton RamRaider, I really appreciate it!  I'll test it.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you RamRaider.  For those who would like to use this script you need to make some changes from Eliza's original script. The table name needs to be changed to "chat" and there are a few extra fields in the chat table that you'll need: ChatType, AgentID, UserID

Comment: Glad you got it sorted with a help of RamRaider :o) Don't forget to accept the answer if it's resolved.